# prove that $D=\overline{\text{span}\{x_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed space. Let $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset E$.

I need to prove that $D=\overline{\text{span}\{x_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is separable.

I've defined $A_n= \left\{ \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j : a_j \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$ and $A= \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

I don't know how to prove that $A$ is dense, and I don't know exactly why $A_k$ is countable.

I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution follows, but I encourage you to think about these hints first:

- approximate $y \in D$ by $x$ in the span of the sequence. Now approximate $x$ by something in $A$. By taking both of these near enough, one should obtain an element of $A$ as near to $y$ as desired.
- union of countable sets are countable, so it suffices to show that each $A_n$ is countable. Think about why finite rational sequences are countable.

Let's see that $A$ is dense in $D$. Pick $y \in D$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. By definition of closure, you can take $x \in \langle x_n \rangle_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\|y-x\| < \varepsilon/2$. Now, the element $x$ must be a finite linear combination of terms of this sequence. There must exist then $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
x = a_1x_1 + \cdots a_nx_n. \tag{1}
$$

Think about why this is true: surely $x$ is a linear combination of some terms, so you can "fill the gaps" between these by choosing $a_i = 0$ obtaining $(1)$.

Finally, by density of the rationals, pick rationals $q_1,\dots,q_n$ such that $|q_i-a_i|\|x_i\| < \varepsilon/2n$ so that noting $z = \sum_{i=1}^nq_ix_i$ we have

$$
\|x-z\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-q_i)x_i\right\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-q_i|\|x_i\| < \varepsilon/2.
$$

Therefore $z \in A$ and $\|y-z\| \leq \|y-x\| + \|x-z\| < \varepsilon$.

Now let's show that $\#A_n$ is countable. Recall that if $X$ is countable, so is $X^n$. Finally, note that the assignment

$$
(q_1,\dots,q_n) \in \mathbb{Q}^n \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^nq_ix_i \in A_n
$$

is surjective, and so $\aleph_0 = \#\mathbb{Q}^n \geq \#A_n$.

Comment: I don't think the map from $A_n$ to $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is well-defined since an element  $x\in A_n$ may have many representations as a linear combination of the $x_i$s. However we have $A_n=\text{span}\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ when $E$ is regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence it is possible to extract a basis from $A_n$ and then obtain a well-defined injective map from $A_n$ to $ \mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: @Alphie hm, I think you are right, it's been a while since I've written this but I think I had assumed the $x_i$ to be linearly independent for some reason. In any case, by the very definition of $\mathrm{span}$ we know that $(q_1, \ldots, q_n) \in \mathbb Q^n \mapsto \sum q_ix_i \in A_n$ is surjective, thus $|A_n| \geq \aleph_0$ (no need to extract a basis). Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: Indeed much simpler! But is my reasoning correct regarding the basis?

Comment: Yes, you are right! If $A$ is generated by (say, a finite set) $S$, then it has some basis $B \subset S$. Thus we have a bijection $k^{|B|} \simeq A$ and $|A| = |k|^{|B|} = |k|$, when $k$ is infinite.